# Portable Power Supply

Tags: battery

I need guidance on how to calculate how long I can power my Pi from an external power bank when I have USB and GPIO peripherals connected.

I am considering buying this [power bank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QSWKNRO) pack.  It says that is delivers: Output: USB1: 5V/1.0A ; USB2: 5V/2.4A and has Capacity: 5000 mAh.  Would this power the pi for at least an hour with a wifi dongle and a gpio type lcd screen?

Any pointers on how to make this calculation and what equipment/measurements I should take to make an educated decision on this purchase?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I looks like this question is about the specs, the product link is just to confirm those and any other specs.

Comment: Yes I edited it to comply can we take it off hold?

Comment: My problem with that is there's already enough [very similar questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+mAh) around that you should be able to read and do some basic arithmetic.   That's when you'll be able to supply the factors (to yourself) that are still missing, such as *"Which pi?"* (they have different power profiles) and *"Exactly how much do **my specific** wifi adapter and LCD screen need?"*.   Anecdotally, I have a 5V 8400 mAh  battery with which a Pi B and camera last maybe 4-6 hours; assuming the wifi + LCD might double the amperage you are probably fine.